# grpc client work only on root user, how to run grpc client on non-root user?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, grpc

I have a simple docker container for my php project

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG WWWUSER
ARG NODE_VERSION=10.16.3

ENV NVM_DIR=/usr/local/nvm

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && echo "keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && gpg --recv-key 0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c \
    && gpg --export 0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c > /usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev \
       php8.1-pgsql php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd \
       php8.1-curl \
       php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring \
       php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap \
       php8.1-intl php8.1-readline \
       php8.1-ldap \
       php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole \
       php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug \
       php8.1-grpc php8.1-imagick php8.1-protobuf \
    && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.1

RUN mkdir $NVM_DIR && chmod -R ugo+rw $NVM_DIR
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash \
    && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u $WWWUSER sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.1/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

start-container script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ ! -z "$WWWUSER" ]; then
    usermod -u $WWWUSER sail
fi

if [ ! -d /.composer ]; then
    mkdir /.composer
fi

chmod -R ugo+rw /.composer

if [ $# -gt 0 ];then
    exec gosu $WWWUSER "$@"
else
    /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
fi
```

I work with google ads api by grpc with proxy flag

```
(new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())
        ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
        ->withDeveloperToken('xxxx')
        ->withLoginCustomerId('xxxx')
        ->withProxy('http://proxy:80/')
        ->build();
```

Also i add on php.ini options for debuging

```
grpc.grpc_verbosity=debug
grpc.grpc_trace=dns_resolver,handshaker
grpc.log_filename=/var/www/html/storage/logs/grpc.log
```

On my host PC i add block record for googleads.googleapis.com to make sure that all requests go through a proxy

```
127.0.0.1 googleads.googleapis.com
```

When I try to make a request from a sail user

```
docker exec -u sail -it php /bin/bash
```

I get an error

```
development.ERROR: { "message": "failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:127.0.0.1:443: Failed to connect to remote host: Connection refused", "code": 14, "status": "UNAVAILABLE", "details": [] }
```

it seems to me that the grpc extension skips the proxy parameter and tries to connect directly to googleads.googleapis.com

Also, there are no entries in the log file

But if I try to do the same thing through a root user

```
docker exec -it php /bin/bash
```

the request goes through a proxy server, and there are entries in the log file.

When debugging the google ads library, I see that the env parameter http_proxy for grpc extension is set in both cases.

How can I get it to work without a root user?

Comment: An `/etc/hosts` file is specific to its filesystem.  A Docker container has its own filesystem, so it doesn't see the host's `/etc/hosts` file.  I'd avoid trying to use `/etc/hosts` here, since it can lead to confusing behavior (especially if you've forgotten you've done it) and inconsistencies across environments (when different hosts or containers have different `hosts` files).